# What causes a guitar's notes to decay/sound out of tune when played together? they sound fine individually, just not when strummed together

Tags: guitar, tuning, intonation

Recently bought this electric guitar, it's great, but I've noticed that when I play chords / strum them all together, the notes on the b and e strings don't resonate in sync with the rest of the strings?

It's hard to explain. Like the notes I play on those strings sound fine when I palm mute/play them individually, but at soon as I let them ring out with the rest of the notes in a chord it sounds out of tune, flat. If I try to compensate for this by tuning them up a bit, then of course it will sound a little sharp for everything else I play.

Also if I use a capo and play the same chords on higher frets, like 7th or 8th, this problem seems to go away. or at least is far less noticeable the higher up you go. The lower you go on the neck, the more pronounced this problem is. when I close my eyes and play the notes, I feel like I can hear it decaying slightly the longer it sustains. It almost sounds like I have a chorus effect going on, but only for notes on those 2 strings and only lower on the fret-board.

Like those specific strings aren't resonating in sync with the rest of the strings when played on lower frets or open notes, you know when you are tuning the strings and you hit the harmonics and listen for any wobbling between the two? That's how it sounds when I play any notes on those two strings lower on the fret-board, even though they are in perfect tune, and playing the notes individually in the same chord formation sounds fine. I've changed the strings, upped the gauge, taken it into the shop and had it set up / worked on. One of the techs I brought it to after having it set up just told me that it's fine, and I must just be pressing too hard on the frets.

I have been playing for over 20 years. I know I'm not pressing too hard. and this happens even when I lightly strum them, plus it makes no sense as it happens on open strings too when played in tandem with other notes. I'm at my wits end with this thing. Please help.

Comment: What happened when you heard the tech play those same chords on the guitar before/after he set it up?

Comment: How close are the pickups to the strings? Drop them back as far as they will go & try again.

Comment: Could you upload an audio sample of the problem?

Comment: when i showed it to the tech he def heard the same problem i heard. but he wasnt the tech who actually worked on it, he passed it off to the senior tech, and the notes he left on it was just "dont push down so hard" and "i adjusted the saddles a bit"   the pickups was a good place to start i thought, but i have lowered and raised them as far down and up as they will go, and it seems to have little to no difference in this problem.  i will try and upload audio clips of what i am talking about when i get home

Comment: also, i know that applying pressure to the back or front of the neck while chords ring out will slightly tighten or loosen the strings causing a change in pitch. but its never been so fragile in any other guitar i have owned. i barely have to touch the back of the neck with one finger and the pitch change in very noticable. im wondering if maybe thats a contributing factor in this problem. because its impossible to not apply any pressure in one way or another while playing chords. though that cant be the whole story cause even open strings have this issue..

Comment: What type of guitar is it? Such as the Les Paul Junior are renowned for not needing a whammy bar, you can get so much pitch-bend out of the neck itself ;)

Comment: its an ESP/LTD EC-1000, well old the james hetfield signature, so i guess its called an ltd truckster. the ugly looking one lolz les paul shape.

Comment: This question seems a little confusing.  You mention "decaying" and resonance, but then intonation.  If chords sound out of tune it could be (1) the guitar is not adjusted properly, (2) your technique is off and you and over compensating by squeezing the strings and bending them out of tune.  But this doesn't say anything about "decaying".

Comment: @JetCaspian - if you can upload sound, or even better, video with sound so we can see and hear what you are doing, we may be able to help. As it stands, your question doesn't really have enough clarity for us to understand what you are trying to describe.

Comment: Yeah, I agree it confuses me just trying to put it I to words. Haha, I'm sorry, I know resonance and decaying seem like separate, easily distinguishable characteristics to differentiate, I'm just having a hard time nailing down what it is exactly. I'm still planning to upload audio/video if I can. I have just been working so much lately I havent had a chance. I will try and do it tomorrow after work.

Comment: I also went out of town today for work, and visited with my sister/met a very knowledgeable guitar tech who took a look at it, and he thinks it's a combination of a few things. 1, intonation was indeed off by a bit, even though two techs already claimed to have adjusted this. And 2, this neck/fretboard is rosewood instead of the standard mahogany and thus, softer than what I'm used too. It doesn't take but a slight touch on either front or back of headstock to seriously alter the notes being played. And 3, he found 2 relatively severe cracks that have been covered up where the neck meets body.

Comment: The store I bought this from claimed that it was new and had just been collecting dust since 2009.but clearly something happened they didnt want to mention involving the neck..the techs I brought it too before were both associated with the store I purchased it from. I had heard somewhat shady things about the store before going there. perhaps next time I'll pay attention to the rumormill. But the this new tech did improve the intonation and did some work to reinforce the neck where the cracks were found. And it performs much better now. But I'm still going to try and record it to show you all